# Show that $2x-\sin{(2x)}-2(\sin{x})\sqrt{x^2-\sin^2{x}}\geq0$ for $x>0$.

Tags: trigonometry, inequality

My question:

> Show that $2x-\sin{(2x)}-2(\sin{x})\sqrt{x^2-\sin^2{x}}\geq0$ for $x>0$.

(Feel free to ignore the rest of this message.)

**Context**
I was trying to solve the following problem, which I made up. The diagram shows a triangle and circular segment sharing a side. The lengths of the sides and arc are shown. Show that the area of the segment cannot be less than the area of the triangle.

[image: Segment and triangle]

The problem is easily solved using the [isoperimetric theorem](https://www.cut-the-knot.org/do_you_know/isoperimetric.shtml). However, I wanted a solution that does not use the isopermetrmic theorem, because I am a high school teacher and I wanted to give this problem to my students, who do not know the isoperimetric theorem.

Trying to solve the problem without the isoperimetric theorem, I let the central angle of the arc (not to be confused with the angle at the bottom of the triangle) be $2x$. Setting the area of the segment to be greater than or equal to the area of the triangle, and simplifying, I got
$$2x-\sin{(2x)}-2(\sin{x})\sqrt{x^2-\sin^2{x}}\geq0\text{ for }0<x<\pi.$$
Using desmos, I realized that something stronger can be shown:
$$2x-\sin{(2x)}-2(\sin{x})\sqrt{x^2-\sin^2{x}}\geq0\text{ for }x>0.$$

So that is where my question comes from.

I am not looking for answers to the question about the segment and triangle, which I mention only as context for the question in the title, which I think is interesting by itself.

**My attempts**
I have tried trigonometric identities, squaring both sides, even Maclaurin series, to no avail. It seems like there is no simple solution.

Comment: I have impression that the inequality reduces to $(x\cos x-\sin x)^2\ge 0.$ I will check it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We will show a slightly stronger version
$$2x-\sin 2x \ge 2|\sin x|\sqrt{x^2-\sin^2x},\qquad x>0$$
i.e.
$$x-\sin x\cos x\ge |\sin x|\sqrt{x^2-\sin^2x}$$
Raising to the square gives
$$x^2+\sin^2x\,(1-\sin^2x)-2x\sin x\cos x\ge \sin^2x\,(x^2-\sin^2x)$$
After moving all terms to the left hand side we get
$$x^2\cos^2x+\sin^2x-2x\sin x\cos x\ge 0$$
The last expression is equal
$$(x\cos x-\sin x)^2$$ therefore the inequality in question holds.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $\sin x>0$ (if $\sin x\le0$, the inequality is clearly true). Your inequality is equivalent to
$$\frac{x}{\sin x}-\cos x\ge\sqrt{x^2-\sin^2{x}}.\tag1$$
After squaring both sides, (1) is equivalent to
$$\frac{x^2}{\sin^2 x}-2x\cot x+\cos^2x\ge{x^2-\sin^2{x}}$$
or
$$\frac{x^2\cos^2x}{\sin^2 x}-2x\cot x+1\ge0$$
or
$$ (x\cot x-1)^2\ge 0$$
which is true.